# ipad camera open view issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode6

i have an issue in my camera view, which is not opened when shoot from iPad. When click on camera button it have do nothing, please anyone help me. I am using xcode 6.4 and OS installed on iPad is 8.4.1

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;

    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

else{


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Unavailable"
                                                   message:@"Unable to find a camera on your device."
                                                  delegate:nil
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    alert = nil;

}
```

Comment: hope you are testing in real device

Comment: yes i use real device @Nitin Gohel

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    NSMutableArray *mediaTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [mediaTypes addObject:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
     picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
     picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

And add MobileCoreServices into your framework.

Comment: i have already MobileCoreServices framework in my framework folder. i use your code but i do nothing and give me this output. Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x17ae5600>  on <MainVC: 0x1750fe60> which is already presenting (null)   @Bhumika